# Proving discontinuity of a piecewise function using $\delta-\epsilon$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

$\text { Let } f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { be defined by } f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text { if } x \leq 0 \\
1 & \text { if } x>0
\end{array}\right.$

I am trying to prove that this function is discontinuous at $0$. Is the following correct?

Set $\epsilon:= a \in [0,1]$. Consider an arbitrary $\delta>0$. Set $x:=\delta - w >0, w>0$. Then $|x|<\delta$ and $|f(x)|=1 \geq a$.

Comment: Technically, yes, I would consider it correct, but it's harder to follow than it needs to be. The answer below is basically the same thing but chooses an explicit $\epsilon$ (don't be afraid to do that in a discontinuity proof!) and doesn't introduce extraneous symbols like $w$ or your $a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, let us stress the definition of continuity on the real line.

We say the function $f:X\to Y$, where $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, is continuous at $a\in X$ iff
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon >0)(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}>0)(\forall x\in X)(|x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

We are now able to deny it to obtain the definition of discontinuity.

We say that a function $f:X\to Y$ (in the same conditions as above) is discontinuous at $a\in X$ iff
\begin{align*}
(\exists\varepsilon > 0)(\forall\delta > 0)(\exists x\in X)((|x - a| < \delta)\wedge(|f(x) - f(a)| \geq \varepsilon))
\end{align*}

In the present case, $a = 0$. Thus it suffices to take $\varepsilon = 1/2$ to make things work.

Indeed, for such value of $\varepsilon$, no matter which value for $\delta > 0$ one chooses, it is enough to consider an $x\in(-\delta,0)$ to obtain $|x - 0| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(0)| = |0 - 1| = 1 \geq \varepsilon$.

Hopefully this helps!